# How to do an OR on a Django ManyToManyField without getting duplicates?

Tags: python, django, orm, many-to-many, django-queryset

I have the following two Django Classes `MyClassA` and `MyClassB`.

`MyClassB` has a many-to-many field of `MyClassA`s

```
from django.db import models

class MyClassA(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return "<%s %s>" % (
        self.__class__.__name__, "; ".join(["ID: %s" % self.pk, "name: %s" % self.name, ]))

class MyClassB(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
    my_class_as = models.ManyToManyField(MyClassA, related_name="MyClassB_my_class_as")

    def __str__(self):
        return "<%s %s>" % (
        self.__class__.__name__, "; ".join(["ID: %s" % self.pk, "name: %s" % self.name, ]))
```

Then I seed the database with the following data:

```
>>> a = MyClassA.objects.create(name="A")
>>> b = MyClassA.objects.create(name="B")
>>> c = MyClassA.objects.create(name="C")
>>> d = MyClassA.objects.create(name="D")
>>> e = MyClassA.objects.create(name="E")
>>> u = MyClassB.objects.create(name="U")
>>> u.my_class_as.add(c)
>>> u.my_class_as.add(d)
>>> u.save()
```

I want to find the (unique) list of MyClassBs that have a relationship with a instance `c` or `d` of MyClassA. How can I do it??

My solution was to create the following static method on `MyClassB`:

```
@staticmethod
def is_m2m_related_queryset(my_class_a_list):
    q = Q()
    for curr_a in my_class_a_list:
        q |= Q(my_class_as=curr_a)
    return q
```

...And then run the following query:

```
>>> MyClassB.objects.filter(MyClassB.is_m2m_related_queryset([c, d]))
[<MyClassB: <MyClassB ID: 11; name: U>>, <MyClassB: <MyClassB ID: 11; name: U>>]
```

But wait! 
Instead of returning to me a singleton list containing the `u` object as I expected, this queryset returns `[u, u]`. That's not what I want. 
Shouldn't this return `[u]`?? 
Why did it return what it did?

How should I get what I want? Should I simply append a `.distinct()` to my queryset? Or is there a better/more efficient for me construct my queryset??

**EDIT:**

I tried Andrey's solution suggested below (and a variant thereof), but that didn't work either:

```
>>> MyClassB.objects.filter(my_class_as__pk__in=[c.pk, d.pk])
[<MyClassB: <MyClassB ID: 1; name: U>>, <MyClassB: <MyClassB ID: 1; name: U>>]

>>> MyClassB.objects.filter(my_class_as__in=[c, d])
[<MyClassB: <MyClassB ID: 1; name: U>>, <MyClassB: <MyClassB ID: 1; name: U>>]
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
MyClassB.objects.filter(my_class_as__pk__in=[c.pk, d.pk])?
```

Comment: Yes, see the Edit on my original question. It didn't give different results.

Comment: Oh, just add `distinct()` at the end. That will give you unique objects.